# Express-session / cookie not being persisted to client

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, cors, netlify

I'm currently working on a dashboard that incorporates third-party oauth2 via discord. I've finally got it working locally by setting a cookie after a user is authorized, before being redirected by:

```
res.cookie('token', tokenData, { secure: false, httpOnly: false})
res.redirect('https://example.com/')
```

At this point in the code, the browser is on the authorization page of the third-party app (Discord), and it's the server communicating with the third-party app, and then setting a cookie, and redirecting back to the client.

Locally, I'm able to send the cookie and it gets read by the client, but once it went into development, as soon as the authorization takes place and I'm redirected to my website, the cookie gets lost. I've tried setting these in the cookie, but it didn't seem to do anything.

```
domain: 'https://.example.com/'
```

I also have my cors middleware with these options, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
{credentials: true, origin: origin}
```

I'm also using axios with

```
{withCredentials: true}
```

My front-end is a React app hosted on Netlify `https://example.com`
My server is hosted on Heroku. `http://api.example.com`
All '/api/*' requests on Netlify are redirected via proxy to `http://api.example.com`

I suspected that it might've been because the server was sending  from http to https, so I ended up creating a dyno on Heroku and tried doing http to http, but the cookie was still being lost.

Locally, it works with my client hosted at `localhost:3000`
and my server at `localhost:8080`

I tried logging the cookie after calling `res.cookie`, and the values of the cookie are actually there, but for some reason, I assume that CORS isn't letting the server set the cookie when it's redirected to the client. I need the cookie in order to authenticate and differentiate between users, and I wanted to avoid using a database just for storing cookies.

I also tried using express-session, but the same thing happens. Works locally, but gets lost in production.

Does it have to do with Heroku, or am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ended up saving the JWT-encoded  into a variable and having the oauth2 third-party callback redirect to
`https://example.com/authenticate` which then calls a GET request to the server at
`https://api.example.com/authenticate` which sends a cookie with the JWT-encoded as the value (weirdly enough this worked and set the cookie for me)

This feels like a hack to me as I have to send another request to the server just to have the cookie set, so I'm open to any ideas about solving the cross-origin issue!

Comment: strangely enough I'm having the exact opposite issue.  My session cookie changes when run locally, but works fine in heroku.